# Sql Server: Timeout expired, alternative solution

Tags: sql-server, timeout

I'm using an application which has the ability to create a backup from an sql server, but the size of it creates an error:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The backup or restore was aborted.
```

What I am wondering is if I am able to change the `time out` time from Management Studio without altering the application.

And if there is no other way but to change the connecion string to the database, does adding a simple `;Connection Timeout=30` to the string solves this problem? The application is written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

> **What I am wondering is if I am able to change the time out time from Management Studio without altering the application.**

- Yes, you can change the timeout in `Management Studio`. See this [article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/01/26/sql-server-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation-or-the-server-is-not-responding/).

> **does adding a simple ;Connection Timeout=30 to the string solves this problem?**

- No, that is the timeout when you connect to your SQL Server, not the query execution timeout.

Comment: Thank you for your respose. The Execution time-out is already set to 0. Which is not time-out. It shouldn't cause an error.